# Downloadable tables in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, download, data.table

**Problem:** Below a toy shiny app from which I want to download the respective transformed data of `mtcars` in the `renderDataTable` expression. I know this was asked a thousand times but I cannot find a reasonable solution as only a html file can be downloaded with useless information or an error is raised using this app.

Many thanks!

**Shiny code**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

source("download_module.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("table"),
    tableDownload_UI("download_data")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      mt_dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
      mt_dt[, .N, by = .(cyl)]
    })

    callModule(tableDownload_server,
               "download_data",
               output$table,
               file_name = "dieterdata.csv"
               )


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Download module**

```
tableDownload_UI <- function(id, label = "Download data"){
  ns <- NS(id)

  downloadButton(ns("download_data"), label)
}

tableDownload_server <- function(input,
                                 output,
                                 session,
                                 data_dev,
                                 file_name){

  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    req(data_dev),

    filename <- function(){
      file_name
    },
    content <- function(file){
      fwrite(data_dev, file)
    }

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the content of an output in another function. This implies that you need first to manipulate your data in a `reactive` environment and then use this reactive expression wherever you want.

Also, there's no need to use `req(data_dev)` in `downloadHandler`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

tableDownload_UI <- function(id, label = "Download data"){
  ns <- NS(id)

  downloadButton(ns("download_data"), label)
}

tableDownload_server <- function(input, output, session, data_dev, file_name){

  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function(){
      file_name
    },
    content = function(file){
      fwrite(data_dev, file)
    }

  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("table"),
  tableDownload_UI("download_data")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  yourdata <- reactive({
    mt_dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
    mt_dt[, .N, by = .(cyl)]
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    yourdata()
  })

  callModule(tableDownload_server,
             "download_data",
             data_dev = yourdata(),
             file_name = "dieterdata.csv"
  )


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```